# docker-machine does not create virtual machine

Tags: docker-machine

I have been going through the Docker get starting [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#create-a-cluster). I can't get docker-machine to create a virtual machine.

My setup:

Host Operating System: Windows 10 Professional

Guest Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04 running on Oracle VirtualBox.

All the Docker stuff is installed on the Ubuntu VM. Oracle VirtualBox is also installed on the Ubuntu machine.

Hyper-Threading is enabled in the BIOS of the physical machine. VirtualBox on Windows 10 also has Hyper-Threading enabled. Despite this, the following command gives an error.

```
 sudo docker-machine create --driver virtualbox myvm1
```

> Running pre-create checks...
>   Error with pre-create check: "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory"

This error makes no sense, because VT-X is already enabled. This led me to try the following:

```
sudo docker-machine create default2 --virtualbox-no-vtx-check
```

This goes well until it tries to get an IP. Then it just hangs at the following:

> Waiting for an IP...

I have tried searching on this. The only answers I can seem to find suggest saving the machine state of the VM created by docker-machine in VirtualBox and then running it in terminal mode. The problem is, there is never a machine created to begin with. I am at a loss of how to proceed. Does anyone know how to troubleshoot from this point forward?

Comment: I am not sure but do you need this ubuntu machine with docker and also virtualbox? Cant you just create machines on your host? Underneath windows also uses docker machine to launch containers.

Comment: I think you are right. This set up is a bit goofy. I am going to give Docker Desktop a try instead.